# Thread.sleep to wait for a window to open

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been using Thread.sleep before doing switching between windows.
I do not like this method, but found it to be the only effective option. 
What I did try was to execute a loop which basically runs for a couple of seconds and then I performed the driver.switchTo.switch (window) in order to avoid the Thread.sleep. However, this does not let me do the switching. Only Thread.sleep does it for me.
Was wondering why this is so. Any inputs. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

What exactly is wrong with it?

You can use the WebDriverWait class, this is basically a wrapper which constantly tries to evaluate a condition and under the hood uses Thread.Sleep().

Thread.Sleep() is fine for this.

Comment: Let me put it this way. One way to do the switch would be  a) switch (window), Thread.sleep(1000) and then access the elements in the new window. Second way, I thought would be : a) switch (window), execute a loop which runs for 1000 msec and then access the elements in the new window. I fail to understand why the second way does not work ! Theoritically both should yield the same results, right?

Comment: I certainly do understand that we have the webdriverwait and implicit wait etc, but that is not what my question is. Thanks.